# Weighted median pyspark dataframes

Tags: python, pyspark

To calculate ***row wise*** weighted median I have written this code. Where am I going wrong that the generated values are coming out to be null? col_A are values and col_B are the weights associated with those values.

Codes:

```
def get_median(values,weights):
    return np.median(np.repeat(values,weights))    # function created to calculate wt. median

wimedian = F.udf(get_median,DoubleType())    # registering as udf here

myview = df.groupBy('category').agg(
    F.collect_list(F.col('col_A')),
    F.collect_list(F.col('col_B'))
).withColumn('Weighted_median',wimedian(F.col('col_A'),F.col('col_B')))

myview.show(3)
```

Output table:

```
+-----------+--------+-------+---------------+
|category   |col_A   |col_B  |Weighted_median|
+-----------+--------+-------+---------------+
|001        |[69]    |[8]    |null           |
|002        |[69]    |[14]   |null           |
|003        |[28, 21]|[3, 1] |null           |
+-----------+--------+-------+---------------+
```

FYI, Correct output for row #3 in this table should be `median of [28,28,28,21] = 28`.
That's why `np.median` and `np.repeat` are there for.

Comment: Can you provide the script to create your df. Or maybe json for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Problem might seems to be return type as dataframe does not understand numpy type and also column references in withColumn statement are incorrect

I convert the type to float and it is running now

```
def get_median(values,weights):
    return float(np.median(np.repeat(values,weights)))

wimedian = F.udf(get_median,DoubleType())
df = sc.parallelize([["001",69,8],["002",69,14],["003",28,3],["003",21,1]]).toDF(["category","col_A","col_B"])

myview = df.groupBy('category').agg(
    F.collect_list(F.col('col_A')),
    F.collect_list(F.col('col_B'))).withColumn('Weighted_median',wimedian(F.col("collect_list(col_A)"),F.col("collect_list(col_B)"))).show()
```

Comment: It does seem to solve the problem temporarily. However it fails again if I replace np.median with np.percentile(q=50). It seems like the return type is not the only problem here.